# Django - Error when viewing HTML template with autogenerated URL link to view function

Tags: django, django-views

I am listing a bunch of items and within the HTML template it contains a URL link to the individual item  (link is auto-generate), but I am getting this error when viewing the page:

```
reverse for 'producer_detail' with arguments '('itemxxx', datetime.datetime(1980, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>))' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['producers/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/\\Z']
```

The table has a UniqueConstraint as there are multiple items with the same owner_name.

```
owner_name = models.CharField(max_length=12, primary_key=True)
logo_svg = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
account_name = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)
metasnapshot_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['owner_name', 'metasnapshot_date'],
                name="producer_idx",
            )
        ]

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.producer_index, name="producer_index"),
    path("<str:pk>/", views.producer_detail, name="producer_detail"),
]
```

**My views**

```
def producer_index(request):
     producers = Producer.objects.all()
     context = {
         'producers': producers
     }
     print(producers)
     return render(request, 'producer_index.html', context)
    
def producer_detail(request, pk, metasnapshot_date):
     producer = Producer.objects.filter(pk=pk,metasnapshot_date=metasnapshot_date)
     context = {
         'producer': producer
     }
     return render(request, 'producer_detail.html', context)
```

**My HTML template to view all items**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
 {% load static %}
 {% block page_content %}
 <h1>Producers</h1>
 <div class="row">
 {% for producer in producers %}
     <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="card mb-2">
             <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ producer.logo_svg }}">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ producer.owner_name }}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ producer.url }}</p>
                 <a href="{% url 'producer_detail' producer.pk producer.metasnapshot_date %}"
                   class="btn btn-primary">
                    Read More
                </a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**HTML to view individual item**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block page_content %}
<h1>{{ producer.owner_name }}</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <img src="{{ producer.logo_svg }}" alt="" width="100%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h5>{{ producer.owner_name }}</h5>
        <h5>{{ producer.pk }}</h5>
        <h5>{{ producer.url }}</h5>

        <br>
        <h5>Technology used:</h5>

    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**The problem I think:**

My guess it's not filtering properly to a single item. I am fairly new to Django so not sure whether my view is configured correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot to pass `metasnapshot_date to the url`
change this

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.producer_index, name="producer_index"),
    path("<str:pk>/", views.producer_detail, name="producer_detail"),
]
```

To

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.producer_index, name="producer_index"),
    path("<str:pk>/<date:metasnapshot_date>/", views.producer_detail, name="producer_detail"),
]
```

**Update**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
def producer_detail(request, pk, metasnapshot_date):
     producer = get_object_or_404(Producer,pk=pk,metasnapshot_date=metasnapshot_date)
     context = {
         'producer': producer
     }
     return render(request, 'producer_detail.html', context)
```

Comment: thanks, using <date: ives the following error:
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: URL route '<str:pk>/<date:metasnapshot_date>/' uses invalid converter 'date'.

Comment: I tried str:metasnapshot_date, which gets rid of the error, but then the individual view doesn't contain any details of the items.

Comment: @Ankh2054 are you sure that every producer has metasnapshot_date ,because if it is not you will get nothing ? i can see that it has null=True and blank=True.

Comment: @Ankh2054 look at this https://pythonshowcase.com/question/how-to-pass-date-and-id-through-url-in-django

Comment: thanks, the error is gone. It item details are still not showing but il have to look into why that is.

Comment: Every producer has a metasnapshot_date set yes.

Comment: @Ankh2054 could you please share your `producer_detail.html` ?

Comment: added to question. The strange think is I can see the single producer result appears in the query set.
<QuerySet [<Producer: Producer object (greeneosiobp)>]>
[14/Mar/2022 14:53:06] "GET /producers/greeneosiobp/1980-01-01/ HTTP/1.1"